# Using sharedViewModel in viewPager fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have an Activity which hosts a viewPager and viewPager has many fragments in it.
To communicate between activity and viewModel for the data and events I am using sharedViewModel.

```
private val viewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

I am registering for the observer in onViewCreated() of fragment. Now here is the problem.
We know how viewPager works with +1 and -1 fragments loaded on either side. As a result of this all 3 fragments are notified about the liveData change.

I have tried below things so far

(1). Use FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT)

/**
* Indicates that only the current fragment will be in the {@link Lifecycle.State#RESUMED}
* state. All other Fragments are capped at {@link Lifecycle.State#STARTED}.
*/

And as per LiveData.observe() doc,

/** The observer will only receive events if the owner is in {@link Lifecycle.State#STARTED}
* or {@link Lifecycle.State#RESUMED} state (active).
*/

So still all 3 fragments would receive the liveData notification as they are in STARTED state.

(2). Observe for liveData change in onResume()
This works for the first fragment. When the viewPager loads for the first time, only the first fragment is receiving the livedata notification. Now when I move to the second fragment, the first fragment still continues to receive the livedata notification.

/**
An observer added with a Lifecycle will be automatically removed if the corresponding Lifecycle moves to DESTROYED state.
*/

How do I handle this scenario, so that I can still use the sharedViewModel and observe for liveData change only in the currently visible fragment.

P.S : The one solution I can think of with the above change is, in onPaused() I have to stop observing for the LiveData change. Is there any other elegant way to solve this ?

Comment: You can create a visibility Listener with the help of pageChangeListener and Set the observer on When the current fragment is visible and remove if page changes . There is no other visible fragment solution which works . Thats the one way i can thing of right now give it a thought .

Comment: Yes @ADM, Thanks. Same thoughts, have the logic for fragmentVisible() and fragmentInvisible().  Any idea on how to remove the observer ?

Comment: You call the listeners in all cases not just for the fragment which is selected . Its like a Broadcast Event and each fragment will hold its position then u can compare to one which is visible . u can use Event bus also i guess . I don't know man this seems messed up little bit maybe there is some better approach to tackle it .